# Redirected to the login page when login as an user in a community

Tags: community, login, grant-login-access, redirection

Hello,

Sometimes, I need touse the "Login" button on an user record page to be connected as him to check things.

This feature works as expected but if I try to go on a community (by clicking on the community name from the app launcher in Salesforce), I am redirected to the login page of this community.

If I click on the community name from the app launcher and I am connected as myself, I am redirected to the community without going the login form page.

This redirection appears yesterday and I am unable to go on the community as the user.

What can I do please?
Is there a feature to enable or disable?

Thanks

Comment: I tried this in my dev org, and could see a redirection to the experience site and not login page. Can you clarify more on your statement "This redirection appears yesterday and I am unable to go on the community as the user" . Also, does the logged-in user have access to the experience site?  Thanks

Comment: The profile of the user has acces to the community (tab "Members" on the community settings).
I was able to connect as the user at the begining of the week but now, I can't anymore because I am redirected to the login page.

But I don't know what changed.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, if we set up the community for the first time, the login page remains assigned to default. We need to first publish the experience builder community page/ visualforce page and we need to assign the same in the login & registration.

[image: Sample Community Login Page Configurations]